# Ubuntu: mailserver + database

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, imap, pop3

I want a mailserver on Ubuntu that saves e-mail in the database and uses users in the database to let them login into the POP server and SMTP server. There are also different domains. How can I do this?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the ISPMail tutorial at http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny even if it was written for Debian Lenny it should work on Ubuntu 10.04.

It explains you how a SMTP server should be configured and how to retrieve emails through IMAP and POP3, you can also use different domains and your users are stored in a MySQL database.